# What is the pseudocode translation for the ema function in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to understanding the underlying function for `ema`.

When I call it, it returns source in `k`.

```
q)ema

k){(*y)(1f-x)\x*y}

q)ema[0.2;til 5]

0 0.2 0.56 1.048 1.6384
```

So far, so good.

When I try to call it directly, it doesn't seem to like the `*`. What am I doing wrong?

```
q){(*y)(1f-x)\x*y}[0.2;til 5]
'*
  [0]  {(*y)(1f-x)\x*y}[0.2;til 5]
         ^
```

How does one describe this `k` phrase in English/pseudocode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark beat me to the exact answer I would give!

One thing to add to his answer, this ema function is using the special shorthand form documented here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#alternative-syntax

Thus,

```
(*y)(1f-x)\x*y
```

is equivalent to

```
{z+x*y}\[first 0 1 2 3 4;1f-0.2;0.2*0 1 2 3 4]
```

which may be a little easier to follow as:

```
{(0.2*z)+x*y}\[0;0.8;0 1 2 3 4]
```

or simply

```
{(0.2*y)+x*0.8}\[0;0 1 2 3 4]
```

aka 0.8 times previous sum plus 0.2 times new value

Answer (score 2):

You can run k code by prepending with `k)` in the command prompt

```
q)k){(*y)(1f-x)\x*y}[0.2;0 1 2 3 4]
0 0.2 0.56 1.048 1.6384
```

Or by passing a string into "k". This allows you to do it in the middle of a statement. You will have to escape backslashes

```
q)"k" "{(*y)(1f-x)\\x*y}[0.2;0 1 2 3 4]"
0 0.2 0.56 1.048 1.6384
```

Comment: Is the documentation for `q` equivalent for `k`; e.g. do `*` and `\\` mean the same thing in both languages?

Comment: The use of \ in ema is as an accumulator and is described here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#alternative-syntax. * is the same as first when a single argument is applied and multiply when two arguments are applied

Comment: The version of k used in kdb+ (k4) isn't documented but you can infer using Sean's tips

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark! Is k not really supposed to be used by the user then?

Comment: I would never use k in a production setting due to the lack of readability which makes it hard for others to understand maintain

Answer (score 2):

To add to Mark and Terry's answers: the reason your code is failing is because `q` does not recognise `*` as anything other than a dyadic (two argument) function. Whereas the `k` interpreter will see it as monadic if it is in the right context (which it is in `ema`).
The `.q` namespace contains the mapping of k function to q keywords so, in future, if you run into similar operators in `k` expressions you should be able to look them up in this namespace. For example:

```
q).q?(*:) // Search for the monadic form of '*'
`first
```

Here you can see that monadic `*` is indeed equivalent to `first`.
This works for other functions:

```
q).q?(>:)
`hclose
q).q?(^:)
`null
q).q?(-:)
`neg
q).q?(=:)
`group
```

This is not guaranteed to work in all cases, and more complex expressions may fail. But it is a good first reference point.

Comment: Thank you Sean, this is very helpful!